# Dockerized WSO2 Identity Server Version 2.3

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am looking for Dockerfiles for the recent WSO 2.3 Identity Server. The files on github seem to be outdated. Is there anything available?

Many thanks!

Comment: are you talking about https://github.com/wso2/dockerfiles which is 7 months old?

Comment: New docker files can be found in - https://github.com/wso2/docker-is